# It can RecorderJs processing a record of a file without emit any sound in speakers meanwhile?

Tags: web-audio-api, recorder.js

While reading some about RecorderJs I ask myself if is possible record a sound without emit any sound in the speakers, all in a background, somebody knows if that is possible? because I don't see something similar in the `Recorderjs` Repository.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use recorder.js, <s>I guess there is a way to feed it directly with a MediaStream, that you'll get from the `streamNode.stream`.</s>
Reading quickly the [source code](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/blob/master/src/recorder.js) of this lib, it seems it only accepts AudioContext Source Nodes, not directly streams, and anyway, you just have to comment the [line 38](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/blob/master/src/recorder.js#L38) of *recorder.js* file.

```js
this.node.connect(this.context.destination);    //this should not be necessary
```

<sup>comment from the author</sup>
And indeed it is.

---

Otherwise, you can also achieve it vanilla style (except that it will save as ogg instead of wav), by using the official [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) API, available in latests browsers.

The main key is the [MediaStreamDestination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamDestination) which doesn't need to be connected to the AudioContext's `destination`.

```js
var audio = new Audio();
audio.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
audio.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/agepbh2agnduknz/camera.mp3';
audio.onloadedmetadata = startRecording;

var aCtx = new AudioContext();
var sourceNode = aCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
var streamNode = aCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
sourceNode.connect(streamNode);

function startRecording() {
  var recorder = new MediaRecorder(streamNode.stream),
    chunks = [];
  recorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    chunks.push(e.data);
  }
  recorder.onstop = function() {
    var blob = new Blob(chunks);
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var a = new Audio(url);
    a.controls = true;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
  }
  audio.onended = function() {
    recorder.stop();
  };
  audio.play();
  recorder.start();
}
```